# Remove/Update JSON key in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, key

I am trying to either update or remove (and then rewrite) a JSON key in node.js

JSON:

```
{"users":[{"Discordid":"discid","Username":"user","Password":"pass","School":"schoolname"}, {"Discordid":"discid1","Username":"user1","Password":"pass1","School":"schoolname1"}]}
```

I want to remove the entire `{"Discordid":"discid","Username":"user","Password":"pass","School":"schoolname"}`
via a **for loop** so I make use of variable `a` which equals the number in which the data is I want to delete.

I have tried:

```
fs.readFile('databases/magistercredentials.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data1) {
     if (err) throw err
     var magistercreds = JSON.parse(data1)
     for (a = 0; a < Object.keys(magistercreds.users).length; a++) delete magistercreds.users[a]
```

And other things which all did not work.

Comment: Why Object.keys(magistercreds.users), if it is an array, not object? Why not magistercreds.users.length?

Comment: And you can use .splice to remove an item, or an empty space will be left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fs.readFile('databases/magistercredentials.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data1) {
     if (err) throw err
     var magistercreds = JSON.parse(data1)
     for (a = 0; a < magistercreds.users.length; a++){
          magistercreds.users.splice( a, 1 );
          a--; // to step back, as we removed an item, and indexes are shifted
     }
```

But may be you want just update, so you can make it simple:

```
fs.readFile('databases/magistercredentials.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data1) {
     if (err) throw err
     var magistercreds = JSON.parse(data1)
     magistercreds.users[68468] = {.....}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't clear on whether a key is to be removed or an entire object. Assuming an entire element is to be removed from the array `users`, the [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can be used.

First find the index of the element you want to remove using `findIndex`. Then you can use `splice` to modify the array in-place.

Sample:

```js
fs.readFile('databases/magistercredentials.json', 'utf-8', function (err, data1) {
     if (err) throw err
     var magistercreds = JSON.parse(data1)
     // Assuming you want to delete the element which has the Discordid property as "discid"
     var indexOfElement = magistercreds.findIndex(el => el.Discordid === "discid")
     magistercreds.users.splice(indexOfElement, 1) // This will remove 1 element from the index "indexOfElement" 
}
```

To add on, using `Object.keys` to iterate over an array is not necessary. The for loop in the original question can be rewritten as:

```js
for (a = 0; a < magistercreds.users.length; a++) delete magistercreds.users[a]
```

Please edit the question to add more information if this is not what you were looking to achieve.